# Pygame screen not updating after each element is added

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to add graphics for my simple sudoku solver program. I want the program to update the displayed sudoku board in real time as it solves it (I thought I would do this by calling my `draw_number` function after every correctly solved number, and then delaying the program, so that it would draw the number, pause, then continue solving.)

However, instead the program solves the whole thing while freezing, then displays the whole solution at once, when its done.

Here is a small-scale example of what im trying to do, which illustrates the problem:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

board = [
    [1,2,3],
    [7,5,6],
    [4,9,8],
]    

def draw_number(r, c, num):

    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 26)
    text = font.render(str(num), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))

    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = ((c+1)*48+11, (r+1)*48+11)
    window.blit(text, text_rect)
    print("Drawing " + str(num) + " at " + str(r+1) + ", " + str(c+1))
    pygame.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    for i in board:
        for j in range(0, 3):
            draw_number(board.index(i), j, board[board.index(i)][j])

            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(20)
    run = False
    pygame.time.delay(5000)
```

When we run this, the simple 3x3 grid should draw individually, with pauses, but instead it finishes the for loops, then pauses for 5000ms, then shows the result for a split second, then closes the program.

I know I am doing something wrong here, but I am new to pygame and not sure what the correct way to do this is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you do pygame.time.delay() it freezes the whole pygame window. In order to prevent this you need to import the time module and then use time.sleep(seconds) instead of the pygame.time.delay()
Here is some code:

```
import pygame
import time
```

Then(skipping the irrelevant parts):

```
run = True
while run:
    for i in board:
        for j in range(0, 3):
            draw_number(board.index(i), j, board[board.index(i)][j])
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I tried this just now, but same exact issue persists.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.  What is suggested in the answer suffers from exactly the same issue as the original code.  The loop is delayed.

Answer (score 1):

PyGame uses an event-driven model for programs.  The code should *never* call `time.sleep()`, or `pygame.time.delay()` etc. because it pauses the program.  If it pauses for long enough, the window manager will consider the program to have stopped responding.

An easy way around this is to time operations with the `pygame.time.get_ticks()`, which returns an every-increasing number of milliseconds since the pygame program started.  Design your program such that it looks at the clock to decide what to do next.

Say you only want to perform an operation every 3 seconds.  Look at the start-time, do the operation, but then don't do anything more (except poll for events and update the screen) until 3000 milliseconds have elapsed.

For example:

```
def doTheThing():
    pass  # TODO: some super-interesting function


time_we_did_the_thing = 0           # When did we last do the thing
clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    # check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    # paint the screen
    screen.fill( ( 0, 40, 200 ) )  # bluish

    # Do the thing, but only every 3 seconds
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if ( time_now > time_we_did_the_thing + 3000 ):
        doTheThing()
        time_we_did_the_thing = time_now

    # flush the screen-updates
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)   # max FPS=60

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi, i attempted using this. I added this inside my solve() method, which is called from my main while loop. inside my solve method, I added a while loop to stall until time_now >= time_we_did_the_thing +1000, and then once this was met, it would continue and run the method for displaying the number on the screen. However, when doing this, i get the same issue, the program stalls until everything is completed, and displays it all at once.

Comment: @RaminKaviani -  The `pygame.display.update()` is being called on every loop iteration right?

Comment: Yeah, I call it right after. Not sure what’s going on. Do I need to rewrite all my code so that it all runs through one main while loop, instead of trying to have a while loop within my solve() function, as well as the main while loop (which calls the solve function )